# Display data from database that has specific login id

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

First, the a lecturer will login. Then the lecturer will be redirect to the dashboard page. It will display the course that the lecturer teach.
Below is the database:
[image]

Login code:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['login_id']) || empty($_POST['login_password'])) {
$error = "ID or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $login_id and $login_password
$login_id=$_POST['login_id'];
$login_password=$_POST['login_password'];

// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$login_id = stripslashes($login_id);
$login_password = stripslashes($login_password);
$login_id = mysql_real_escape_string($login_id);
$login_password = mysql_real_escape_string($login_password);

// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("attendance_system", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where login_id='$login_id' AND login_password='$login_password'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
    if (strlen($login_id) == 10) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$login_id; // Initializing Session
    header("location: dashboard-lecturer.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    }
    if (strlen($login_id) == 6) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$login_id; // Initializing Session
    header("location: dashboard-HEA.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    }
    if (strlen($login_id) == 5) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$login_id; // Initializing Session
    header("location: dashboard-prog_coordinator.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    }
} else {
$error = "ID or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

My scratch code to display the data:

```
<?php
$counter = 1;

$data = "SELECT * FROM course";         
                    $result = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error());                         

                        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
                        {

                        $course_code = $info['course_code'] ;
                        $course_name = $info['course_name'] ;
?>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><?php echo $counter; 
                                                        $counter++; ?>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $course_code; ?>
                                                            <ul class="table-mobile-ul visible-xs list-unstyled">
                                                                <li>Course Name: <?php echo $course_name; ?></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $course_name; ?></td>
                                                        <td class='col-medium center'><a href='lec/stud_att_record.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>View Students Attendance</button></a></td>
                                                    </tr>                                                   
<?php
}
?>
```

My problem is that I dont know how to code for the SELECT query so that the course displayed will only show the course that the lecturer teach only.

Comment: Already stated at the bottom of my post @anantkumarsingh

Comment: Is there any relationship between lecturer and courses? because i didn't see any relation in your db structure? Also lecturer belongs to which table?

Comment: The lecturer data is in the staff table. The relationship that i've made is on the studentAttendance, where both staff and course foreign key is put in the studentAttendance table (the staff_staff_id and the course_course_code). I do not put a direct relationship for the staff table and the course table as more than one lecturer will possibly teach the same course. So, I want to avoid redundant data in the course table.. @anantkumarsingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, I want to avoid redundant data in the course table

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Each time u want to avoid redundants datas in the course table.
**THESE datas will go into** the studentAttendance Table.

BUT nb_students > nb_teachers (i believe) :

Therefore u'll get tons of informations in the student presence table (the classroom, the program, the semester) which belongs **FOR ME** to the course table and **are redudants**.

Anyway the only way i see to get all the courses the lecturer do is :

```
- JOIN the StudentAttendance with login_id of the current teacher
Result : returns all the student present in ALL the teacher's courses.

-  + GROUP BY id_course 
Result : returns all the teacher's course_id

- + JOIN with course_table 
Result : so we'll able to display the name of the course instead of id.

EDIT :
- JOIN staff table with login table 
Result : so u target the teacher related to the $_SESSION('login_id').
```

QUERY will looks like this :

```
SELECT course_name, staffAttendance.course_course_id
FROM login, course, staff, staffAttendance
WHERE staffAttendance.staff_staff_id = staff.staff_id AND
      staffAttendance.course_course_code = course.course_code AND
      staff.login_login_id = login.login_id AND 
      login.login_id = $_SESSION['login_user'] 

GROUP BY staffAttendance.course_course_id
```

BTW it's very ugly.

Comment: Yes.. I want the studentAttendance table to be the transactional table. while the other tables will provide additional information to certain data. Hmm now I think that the login table is not required, right? Just enough with the staff table. The login table will add up the complication. Or is it just okay to be there? What u think? @Falt4rm

Comment: Anddd after a little changes to the query you've made, it WORKS VERY WELL! TQSM!! @Falt4rm

Comment: Yeah My bad. Forgot to finish it. Edited BTW. Glad u went through it. Oh last little thing i forgot too :  u should consider inheritance from login --> staff + students table in case one day u would have to make a page that allows students to see the courses they missed/ will have to go. Best regards, Falt